# "Error: Incorrect no.of dimensions" when plotting multivariate data in Vegan

Tags: r, plot, permutation, vegan

I am getting the following error when I try to plot a model I created with `vegdist` in the `vegan` package of R.

```
#Error in x$vectors[take, axes][ch, ] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

I am trying to see if the species assemblage of animals differs between days of the week at a single site. 
My code is listed below, complete with annotations as to what I am trying to do at each step.

```
#reshape my data (df1) into a new multivariate dataframe
dfnew<-dcast(df1, DayOfWeek + SessionID ~ SpeciesName, fill = NULL)
#find out how many species there are
x <- length(dfnew)
#remove the rows (if any) that do not contain any values at all (excluding the first 2 columns which are actually factors we will use in the next step)
dfnew <- dfnew[rowSums(is.na(dfnew)) != ncol(dfnew[,3:x]),] 
#finally, convert all na's to zeros
dfnew[is.na(dfnew)] <- 0

#make two separate data frames to hold the data (dfspecies), and the factors (dfDoW)
dfDoW <- data.frame(dfnew$DayOfWeek)
dfspecies <- data.frame(dfnew[,-1:-2])

library("vegan", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.2")
#create a resemblance matrix based off bray-curtis distances (best for comparing species assemblages)
dis <- vegdist(dfspecies, method = "bray")
#create the factor we need to test
groups <- factor(dfDoW$dfnew.DayOfWeek)
#create a model of how the species assemblage varies between days of the week
mod <- betadisper(dis, groups)
#plot the model into a PCoA plot
plot(mod)
#test if species varies according to day of week
permutest(mod, pairwise = T)
```

Now, the part where the error occurs is the second last line "plot(mod)"

```
#Error in x$vectors[take, axes][ch, ] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

I have looked at the `str()` of the `data.frame` to make sure they match (they do).

The crazy part is that this exact code works perfectly for another factor that I am testing on the same data (time of day).

I think the model is actually running because the `permute` line of code provides output.

I provide a screenshot of a small demo dataset below that I can extrapolate back to my code.

If anyone can please help that would be great, thanks!

[image: Small demo dataset]

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of your data. not an image. You can do `dput(df1)`.

Comment: I can generate the same error message if `groups` has a factor level with only one case. For instance: `data(dune); d <- vegdist(dune); gr <- rep("A", nrow(dune)); gr[3] <- "B"; mod <- betadisper(d, gr); plot(mod)`. Is this the case with your data?

Answer (score 0):

There is no reproducible example, but I managed to trigger the very same error message when I had a group with only one member. This problem is now fixed in https://github.com/vegandevs/vegan, and this fix will be in the next **vegan** release. If only possible, check the github fix and report about its success (both success and failure are equally interesting).

Comment: Thank you Jari! Yes, one of my levels of the factor has only 1 replicate (Friday). I will update on the next vegan release as you suggest. In the meantime, I will just exclude that level of the factor, it's not really necessary right now anyway.

Comment: This is now fixed in **vegan** release 2.5-2 in CRAN.